# Customize contents of OpenLayers map attribution

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm trying to build my own map attribution function and I want to see inside it a specific content.

```
function MapAttribution() {
  const attribution = new ol.control.Attribution({
    className: 'ol-attribution',
    label: 'a',
    collapsible: true,
    collapsed: true,
    target: document.getElementById('map-attribution'),
    text: '<a href="https://www.w3schools.com">Visit W3Schools</a>'
  });
  map.addControl(attribution);

  return attribution;
};
```

The problem is that I don't understand where I can put my text.

**NOTE**: I try to create one shared component for all maps with the same text inside. I know that I can use:

```
new TileLayer({
  source: new OSM({
    attributions: "<a href="https://www.w3schools.com">Visit W3Schools</a>"
  })
})
```

But I don't want to use it.

Comment: The text used by the control is set in the layer source https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-forked-b9k11

Comment: Yes I know, but I try to create one shared component for all maps with the same text inside

Comment: When I need that I add an extra layer `var attribLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({source: new ol.source.Vector({ attributions: 'HELLO'})});`

Comment: It is smart thing, thank you :)
So, I can solve this problem only with a workaround at moment?

Comment: If it's simple text you could use CSS `.ol-attribution::before` or `.ol-attribution::after`  modifier.

Comment: It is not a simple text

Comment: But above in your example code it is simple text.

Comment: You are right, I've edit the question with my idea